# How to detect and handle firebase Permission Denied error code with swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the following error while observe data from firebase realtime database. What I want to do is if the error is Permission Denied, I want to do a different action. How can I tell if the error is Permission Denied?

error :

> Optional(Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission Denied})

mycode:

```
func observeData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
    Database.database().reference().child("values").observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
        completion(true)
    }){ (error) in
        let errorCode = (error as NSError).code
        if errorCode == .?????? {  //-->> what to come here
            self.anotherFunc()  //--> if Permission Denied call this func
            completion(false)
        }else{
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is actually really good. Here's the minor change; you have a function that calls `observe data' which contains a closure following that call. Within - *that* - closure you're handling a return value of true or false. If a false value is returned then call the next function you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for Auth errors in my firebase app. Not sure if it will work in your context, but you might find it useful.

```
func firebaseErrorParser(error: Error) -> String? {
    if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) { // <- here!!

        switch errorCode { // switch case
        case .invalidVerificationCode:
            return "Wrong code or phone number!"
        default:
            return "An error occured... "
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I only had one entry in my switch/case because the only error I wanted to give specific feedback to the user about was if the user entered the wrong phone number. It seems like you can do something similar with firestore permissions errors